# Can we rename contact standard field label in the work order?

Tags: administration, standard-objects, admin, standard-field

Is that possible to rename contact standard field in the work order object? I tried using Setup -> Customize -> Tab Names and Labels -> Rename Tabs and Labels. But Contact standard field is not visible there. Any idea on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot rename contact label on workorder from rename tabs and labels because contact is a lookup on workorder.
To achieve this, you will have to rename contact object itself from rename tabs and labels Note that when you do this contact look up labels on all objects will now the renamed label